# Get line number with abstract syntax tree in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, abstract-syntax-tree

Im making a program that takes some code via parameter, and transform the code adding some console.logs to the code. This is the program:

```
const escodegen = require('escodegen');
const espree = require('espree');
const estraverse = require('estraverse');

function addLogging(code) {
    const ast = espree.parse(code);
    estraverse.traverse(ast, {
        enter: function(node, parent) {
            if (node.type === 'FunctionDeclaration' ||
                node.type === 'FunctionExpression') {
                addBeforeCode(node);
            }
        }
    });
    return escodegen.generate(ast);
}

function addBeforeCode(node) {
    const name = node.id ? node.id.name : '<anonymous function>';
    const beforeCode = "console.log('Entering " + name + "()');";
    const beforeNodes = espree.parse(beforeCode).body;
    node.body.body = beforeNodes.concat(node.body.body);
}
```

So if we pass this code to the function:

```
console.log(addLogging(`
function foo(a, b) {   
  var x = 'blah';   
  var y = (function () {
    return 3;
  })();
}
foo(1, 'wut', 3);
`));
```

This is the output of this program:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log('Entering foo()');
    var x = 'blah';
    var y = function () {
        console.log('Entering <anonymous function>()');
        return 3;
    }();
}
foo(1, 'wut', 3);
```

And this is the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) for that last function passed to addLoggin:

https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/b5826862c47dfb7dbb54cec15079b430/latest

So i wanted to add more information to the console logs like for example the line number we are on. As far as i know, in the ast, the node has a value caled 'start' and 'end' which indicates in which character that node starts and where it ends. How can i use this to get the line number we are on? Seems pretty confusing to me to be honest. I was thinking about doing a split of the file by "\n", so that way i have the total line numbers, but then how can i know i which one im on?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As the code will be regenerated at the end, the line numbers in the source will not be the same as the line numbers in the result. Blank lines are removed, line breaks may be added,  the `console.log` additions add lines. So: to which version of the code should the line numbers refer to? The source code or the returned code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is fine. First find the offsets in the original code where each line starts. Then compare the `start` index of the node with those collected indexes to determine the line number.

I will assume here that you want the reported line number to refer to the *original* code, not the code as it is returned by your function.

So from bottom up, make the following changes. First expect the line number as argument to `addBeforeCode`:

```
function addBeforeCode(node, lineNum) {
    const name = node.id ? node.id.name : '<anonymous function>';
    const beforeCode = `console.log("${lineNum}: Entering ${name}()");`;
    const beforeNodes = espree.parse(beforeCode).body;
    node.body.body = beforeNodes.concat(node.body.body);
}
```

Define a function to collect the offsets in the original code that correspond to the starts of the lines:

```
function getLineOffsets(str) {
    const regex = /\r?\n/g;
    const offsets = [0];
    while (regex.exec(str)) offsets.push(regex.lastIndex);
    offsets.push(str.length);
    return offsets;
}
```

NB: If you have support for `matchAll`, then the above can be written a bit more concise.

Then use the above in your main function:

```
function addLogging(code) {
    const lineStarts = getLineOffsets(code);   // <---
    let lineNum = 0;                           // <---
    const ast = espree.parse(code);
    estraverse.traverse(ast, {
        enter: function(node, parent) {
            if (node.type === 'FunctionDeclaration' ||
                     node.type === 'FunctionExpression') {
                // Look for the corresponding line number in the source code:
                while (lineStarts[lineNum] < node.body.body[0].start) lineNum++;
                // Actually we now went one line too far, so pass one less:
                addBeforeCode(node, lineNum-1);
            }
        }
    });
    return escodegen.generate(ast);
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but be aware that functions can be arrow functions, which have an expression syntax. So they would not have a block, and you would not be able to inject a `console.log` in the same way. You might want to make your code capable to deal with that, or alternatively, to skip over those.